# Each time I sort a list of floats (which has nan values) I get a different list python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to sort a list of floats (and nan values) in python like:

```
print max(list)
list.sort()
list.reverse()
for i in range(100):
    print list[i]
nan
nan
2.0803176458
nan
nan
23.1620761136
15.9680303803
15.3134388394
14.68055076
11.450492644
8.96268420227
8.15331554187
5.24420616524
3.9665322752
3.69758305442
1.08500491226
-0.227894225141
-0.254784399765
-0.866879940573
-1.21267324819
-2.21811678021
nan
nan
2.69325878444
```

when I run it I get different values for the max most times and my list is not sorted when it prints out (results are under the code above)

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

Comment: Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240050/python-sort-function-breaks-in-the-presence-of-nan).

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> float('nan') < 3.14
False
>>> float('nan') > 3.14
False
>>> float('nan') < float('nan')
False
>>> float('nan') > float('nan')
False
>>> float('nan') == float('nan')
False
```

The problem is that `nan` doesn't have an ordering with respect to other numbers. Comparisons always return False, whether that's against numbers or other `nan` values. The contract for `sort()` requires that list items have a consistent ordering in order to sort correctly.

To sort `nan` you'll need to override this behavior and define how you want `nan` to sort. For instance, if you want it to come before all other numbers you could use a `key` function to make `nan` equivalent to `-inf`.

```
>>> l = [float('nan'), 3.14, -1, 0, float('nan')]
>>> import math
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda f: float('-inf') if math.isnan(f) else f)
[nan, nan, -1, 0, 3.14]
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because a `nan` can't be compared to any other object(not even itself).

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> y = x
>>> y == x
False
```

Use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/%E2%80%8E) to handle `nan`'s properly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(nums)
>>> np.sort(arr)
array([ -2.21811678,  -1.21267325,  -0.86687994,  -0.2547844 ,
        -0.22789423,   1.08500491,   2.08031765,   2.69325878,
         3.69758305,   3.96653228,   5.24420617,   8.15331554,
         8.9626842 ,  11.45049264,  14.68055076,  15.31343884,
        15.96803038,  23.16207611,          nan,          nan,
                nan,          nan,          nan,          nan])
>>> np.nanmax(arr)
23.162076113600001
>>> np.nanmin(arr)
-2.2181167802099999
```