# Why does sorted() not sort an array that contains nan values?

Tags: python, numpy

It seems like when "nan" values are included in a Numpy array, the array cannot be sorted though `sorted()`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([float('nan'),2,float('nan'),1],dtype=float)
valuesSorted = sorted(values)
print(valuesSorted)
```

The output is `[nan, 2.0, nan, 1.0]`. Whereas if you sort `[2,1]` with the same code, the output is `[1.0,2.0]`.

Alternatively, if  you use `values.sort()`:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([float('nan'),2,float('nan'),1],dtype=float)
values.sort()
print(values)
```

The output is: `[ 1.  2. nan nan]`, meaning that `sort()` can sort arrays that include nan values.

My questions are: why does the function `sorted()` not sort an array containing nan values? Is it possible to use `sorted()` to sort an array containing nan values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240050/python-sort-function-breaks-in-the-presence-of-nan

Comment: As for why it works in Numpy - from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html): _Previous to numpy 1.4.0 sorting real and complex arrays containing nan values led to undefined behaviour. In numpy versions >= 1.4.0 nan values are sorted to the end._

Comment: @Pythonista Ah, I didn't know the right keywords to search for. I also just realized that `sorted()` is not implemented by Numpy (which I thought was the case), instead the underlying list is passed to the builtin function.

Comment: @ME914 there is no underlying list, but sorted creates a list out of the iterable you pass to it.