# Why doesn't NaN raise any errors in python?

Tags: python

In my opinion, things like `float('nan')` should be optimized, but apparently they aren't in Python.

```
>>> NaN = float('nan')
>>> a = [ 1, 2, 3, NaN ]
>>> NaN in a
True
>>> float('nan') in a
False
```

Does it have any meaning with not optimizing `nan` like other things?
In my thought, `nan` is only `nan`.

As well as this, when you use `sorted` on these things, they give weird results:

```
>>> sorted([3, nan, 4, 2, nan, 1])
[3, nan, 1, 2, 4, nan]


>>> 3 > float('nan')
False
>>> 3 < float('nan')
False
```

The comparison on `nan` is defined like this, but it doesn't seems 'pythonic' to me. Why doesn't it raise an error?

Comment: I like the observation and I think it's confusing, too. Which of the 7 statements should raise an exception?

Comment: In C# the result is `[NaN, NaN, 1,2,3,4]` which is more pythonic, IMHO.

Comment: The simple answer is "because that's how IEEE754 defines it for reasons that, at least at the time it was defined made sense to at least the people defining the standard".

Comment: In fact; the idea is that NaN is "not a value" so its comparison with any value is always False, including with itself.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: do you have a reference where IEEE754 defines how floats shall be sorted? I'd like to read that

Comment: The implementation of NaN is also consistent with other operations: 2 + NaN gives NaN for instance.

Comment: For the sorting, I think that'll depend on the sorting algorithm, and how stable it is. If the sorting algorithm compares for *in*equality, the NaN would be regarded as equal to the value compared to (since `x > NaN` evaluates to False, so the sorting algorithm will see them equal, or rather, as not-non-equal), and leave it in-place (stable sort).

Comment: One interesting feature of NaN is that it breaks the "(a is b) implies (a==b)" protocol, and the `in` operator checks identity before it checks equality. This means that `x in somelist` can be true at the same time as `all(x != y for y in somelist)`.

Comment: Note that NumPy produces `array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan, nan])`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: .NET also uses IEEE754 for floats, but still behaves differently.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240050/python-sort-function-breaks-in-the-presence-of-nan (seems to be close enough to count as a duplicate of this question).

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"?

Comment: For "optimization" I meant making the id of  `float('nan')` all the same for memory savings.  Sorry if it sounded vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Membership testing**

Two different instances of `float('nan')` are not equal to each other. They are "Not a Number" so it makes sense that they shouldn't also have to be equal. They are different instances of objects which are not numbers:

```
print(float('nan') == float('nan'))  # False
```

As documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or
> collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(**x is e**
> or x == e for e in y).

There is a checking for identity! that's why you see that behavior in your question and why `NaN in a` returns `True` and `float('nan') in a` doesn't.

---

**Sorting in Python**

Python uses the [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm for its `sorted()` function. (Also see [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt) for a textual explanation.) I'm not going to go into that. I just want to demonstrate a simple example:

This is my class `A`. It's going to be our `float('nan')` object. It acts like `float('nan')` in that it returns `False` for all comparison operations:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __lt__(self, other):
        print(self, 'lt is calling', other)
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        print(self, 'gt is calling', other)
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'A({self.n})'

class B:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __lt__(self, other):
        print(self, 'lt is calling', other)
        return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        print(self, 'gt is calling', other)
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'B({self.n})'
```

When we use the `sorted()` function (or the `.sort()` method of a `list`) without the `reverse=True` argument, we're asking for the iterable to be sorted in ascending order. To do this, Python tries to call the `__lt__` method successively, starting from the second object in the list to see if it is less than its previous object and so on:

```
lst = [A(1), B(2), A(3), B(4)]
print(sorted(lst))
```

output :

```
B(2) lt is calling A(1)
A(3) lt is calling B(2)
B(4) lt is calling A(3)
[A(1), B(2), A(3), B(4)]
```

Now, switching back to your example:

```
lst = [3, A(1), 4, 2, A(1), 1]
print(sorted(lst))
```

output:

```
A(1) lt is calling 3
A(1) gt is calling 4
A(1) gt is calling 2
A(1) lt is calling 2
A(1) lt is calling 4
A(1) gt is calling 1
[3, A(1), 1, 2, 4, A(1)]
```

1. `A(1).__lt__(3)` will return `False`. This means `A(1)` is not less
   than 3 or This means `3` is in correct position relative to `A(1)`.
2. Then here `int.__lt__(4, A(1))` gets called and because it returns
   `NotImplemented` object, Python checks to see if `A(1)` has
   implemented `__gt__` and yes, so `A(1).__gt__(4)` will return
   `False` again and this means the `A(1)` object is in correct place
   relative to `4`.
3. *(Etc.)*

This is why the result of `sorted()` seems to be weird, but it's predictable. `A(1)` object in both cases, I mean when `int` class returns `NotImplemented` and when `__lt__` gets called from `A(1)`, **will** return False.

It's better to check the [Timsort](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt) algorithm and consider those points. I would include the remaining steps if I read Timsort algorithm carefully.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Thanks, corrected and also updated with better example.

Comment: Yes, nicer with the B. Could also make B behave like an int instead, i.e., compare normally with other B objects and return NotImplemented with A objects. Then we would see that `int.__lt__(4, A(1))` call in the output