# Internal min function of python

Tags: python, function, internal, min

I need to know how the min function of python works if there are more than one item in a list which are minimum. Which one takes min? Say A = [5, 3, 1, 4, 1]. Now if I say A.remove(min(A)) which one will be removed? The first 1 or the second 1?

Comment: For what it's worth, It might be more illustrative to say, `A = [(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)]; A.remove(min(A,key=itemgetter(0)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it will remove the first one.  It's more about the behavior of the `list.remove` function rather than the `min` function in this case.  `min` just returns the lowest value in the list so it returns the integer `1`.  `list.remove` removes the leftmost instance of the parameter passed to it.

Also, as answered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6783101/893324) to the question that mgilson linked above, if you are dealing with objects rather than values (i.e. lists rather than integers), the first one matching the minimum value will be selected.