# Does min with lambda always return the first value in python?

Tags: python, lambda

In python 2.7.3, using the min function with a lambda, such as `min(list, key=f)` where `f` is an lambda function. If it was the case that `f(x)` was always the same value for all `x` in list, is it guaranteed that `list[0]` will be returned?

Thanks

Comment: probably? depends on the implementation of `min`. Does it really matter, since you have already predicated the example on the fact that they are all equal?

Comment: In my program, it does matter, it has to do with specific functionality of the code. Nevertheless I would still like to know if this is true or not.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, `f(0) == f(1)` but may be `l[0] != l[1]`

Comment: @omega, I was explaining HunterMcMillen why it might matter.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of [Which maximum does Python pick in the case of a tie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783000/which-maximum-does-python-pick-in-the-case-of-a-tie)

Comment: @elyase Well now you are assuming you know what data this function is operating on. For the case of `min([3,3,3], key=lambda x: x)`, `f(0) = f(1)` AND `l[0] = l[1]`.

Comment: Elyase did say 'may be' not equals so it could still equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CPython and PyPy yes. You can see in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e280a04625cc/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1372) that the `maxval` is updated only if the current value is lower than the `maxval`. Note that internally in CPython same function(`min_max`) is being used for both `min()` and `mix()`, the only difference is the [`op` passed](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare) is case of both: for `min` it's `Py_LT` and for `max` it's `Py_GT`.

```
maxitem = NULL; /* the result */
maxval = NULL;  /* the value associated with the result */
while (( item = PyIter_Next(it) )) {
    /* get the value from the key function */
    if (keyfunc != NULL) {
        val = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(keyfunc, item, NULL);
        if (val == NULL)
            goto Fail_it_item;
    }
    /* no key function; the value is the item */
    else {
        val = item;
        Py_INCREF(val);
    }

    /* maximum value and item are unset; set them */
    if (maxval == NULL) {
        maxitem = item;
        maxval = val;
    }
    /* maximum value and item are set; update them as necessary */
    else {
        int cmp = PyObject_RichCompareBool(val, maxval, op);
        if (cmp < 0)
            goto Fail_it_item_and_val;
        else if (cmp > 0) {
            Py_DECREF(maxval);
            Py_DECREF(maxitem);
            maxval = val;
            maxitem = item;
        }
        else {
            Py_DECREF(item);
            Py_DECREF(val);
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Same case with PyPy](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/b9d53b23c50b0e14f2ca996b762ae2c450ea8301/pypy/module/__builtin__/functional.py?at=default#cl-188), `w_max_item` and `w_max_val` are updated only if the item is the first item from the sequence or if it satisfies the condition as per the function chosen based on the value of `implementation_of`("max" or "min"):

```
if not has_item or \
        space.is_true(compare(w_compare_with, w_max_val)):
    has_item = True
    w_max_item = w_item
    w_max_val = w_compare_with
```

Comment: What is `CPython`?. The python I am using is on a linux machine.

Comment: @omega It's an implementation of Python(default one).

Comment: In the light of the fact that this is undocumented, should we avoid writing Python code that assumes that CPython behaves this way? I doubt the implementation would ever change in a way that would break this behavior (it's in essence a de facto part of the API by now), but it's not a guarantee, I guess.

Comment: Ah! In Python 2 this is undocumented, but in Python 3.4 we have [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#min): "If multiple items are minimal, the function returns the first one encountered."

Answer (score 0):

As Ashwini writes in his excellent answer, the implementation of CPython is such that the first result will be returned in the case of a tie. In the [Python 3.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#min), this behavior is explicitly stated:

> If multiple items are minimal, the function returns the first one
>   encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving
>   tools such as sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc)[0] and heapq.nsmallest(1,
>   iterable, key=keyfunc).

Unfortunately there is no such statement in the Python 2 documentation: `min`'s behavior upon encountering multiple minimal items is undefined as far as the documentation is concerned. This means that the CPython interpreter makes no guarantee that this behavior will be around in future versions, though one might argue that since this functionality is so well-known and established it is a *de facto* aspect of the language.

If you'd like to be *really* careful and explicit, you can define a function that is guaranteed to find the first minimum according to the Python 2 API:

```
def first_min(iterable, **kwargs):
    wrapped = ((x,i) for i,x in enumerate(x))
    if "key" in kwargs:
        keyfun = kwargs["key"]
        kwargs["key"] = lambda x: (keyfun(x[0]), x[1])
    return min(wrapped, **kwargs)[0]
```

Whether or not you use it over the built-in `min` depends upon how seriously you regard sticking to the defined and documented behavior.